# Notational question

Tags: notation

We are in the framework of measurable transformations, i.e.
let $(X,\mathcal{B},m)$ be a measure space and let $T:X\to X$ be a measurable transformation.

In your opinion, what does the following notation mean?

$$
T^{-n}(A)\qquad\text{for}\quad A\in\mathcal{B}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The $n$-th preimage of $A$ under $T$, that is 
$$ T^{-1}(A) = \{x \in X \mid Tx \in A \} $$
denotes the preimage of $A$ under $T$, and we interate this by 
$$ T^{-n}(A) := T^{-1}\bigl(T^{1-n}(A)\bigr), n \ge 2 $$
or what is the same, the preimage under $T^n = T \circ \cdots \circ T$ of $A$, that is
$$ T^{-n}(A) = \{x \in X \mid T^nx \in A\} $$

Answer (score 1):

This is the set of elements $x \in X$ that if you apply $T$ to them $n$ times, you land in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: $\{x\in X:T^nx\in\mathcal{B}\}$, that is $T^{-n}:=({T^n})^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, this is my guess.